# updating an ng-grid cell

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I'm displaying an ng-grid and I would like to change a particular cell's content based on an update.  I don't want to make the cell editable.  I'm instead popping up a dialog when they click on a Row.  When they submit the data, I update the db using ajax, but I don't want to refresh the page.  I'd like to update the cell to say something like "Updated".  I haven't found anything in documentation or examples that would allow me to modify a particular cell on the fly.  Anybody wanna point me in a right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do something similar with my data. Use a row or cell template to show your dialog using ng-click and pass a reference to the row.entity to your dialog. Then you can just update the data on the row.

I created an example below where I have a cell template that has an event to capture the row, column, and cell data. Then I allow for the user to update the value, and on the button click I update the row with the new value.

Plunkr here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/JQ7mtD?p=preview